# Google speech to text api v1: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am using google speech to text to record calls and sent it to the google's server to convert the flac audio file into text. everything is working fine in android 5.0 and previous versions but from 5.02 and above I am getting the following error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x8f548: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
```

I am using **google speech api v1**. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this?

this is the method which is throwing the exception..

```
private Scanner openHttpsPostConnection(String urlStr, byte[] data) {
    InputStream in = null;
    byte[] mextrad = data;
    int resCode = -1;
    OutputStream out = null;
    // int http_status;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpsURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException("URL is not an Https URL");
        }

        HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //httpConn.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac; rate=1600");
                //+ sampleRate);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("AcceptEncoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        httpConn.connect();

        try {
            // this opens a connection, then sends POST & headers.
            out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
            // Note : if the audio is more than 15 seconds
            // dont write it to UrlConnInputStream all in one block as this
            // sample does.
            // Rather, segment the byteArray and on intermittently, sleeping
            // thread
            // supply bytes to the urlConn Stream at a rate that approaches
            // the bitrate ( =30K per sec. in this instance ).
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "IO beg on data");
            out.write(mextrad); // one big block supplied instantly to the
                                // underlying chunker wont work for duration
                                // > 15 s.
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "IO fin on data");
            // do you need the trailer?
            // NOW you can look at the status.
            resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            Log.d("ParseStarter", "POST OK resp: " +resCode+" "
                    + httpConn.getResponseMessage().getBytes().toString());

            if (resCode / 100 != 2) {
                Log.d("ParseStarter", "POST bad io ");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "FATAL " + e);

        }

        if (resCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "OK RESP to POST return scanner ");
            return new Scanner(httpConn.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code that gives the error?

Comment: I have added the code please have a look

Answer (score 0):

OutputStream cannot write on the server by it is own. You need to create a BufferedWriter to write on the server after you get your OutputStream.

```
.
.
.
try {
// this opens a connection, then sends POST & headers.
out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
// Note : if the audio is more than 15 seconds
// dont write it to UrlConnInputStream all in one block as this
// sample does.
// Rather, segment the byteArray and on intermittently, sleeping
// thread
// supply bytes to the urlConn Stream at a rate that approaches
// the bitrate ( =30K per sec. in this instance ).
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(mextrad);
.
.
.
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to check your data type. In that case, can you try to change:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(mextrad);
```

to

```
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(out);
stream.writeBytes(mextrad);
```

I never tried this in Android before but I hope it will help.

Comment: BufferedWriter cant write byte array

Comment: Its still not working. you probably didnt get my problem my app runs perfectly in android 5.0(lolipop) but the problem starts after that version.